# How to have title columns for each PHP column result

Tags: php, html

I would like individual column titles to display for each table data column that is echo'd?

```
<form>
<?php 

$numeroOption= $_POST['numero'];
$roomtype= $_POST['roomtype'];
$selectOption = $_POST['parkname'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM `ROOMS` WHERE `Capacity` < '$numeroOption' AND `Park` LIKE '$selectOption%' AND `dataProjector` LIKE '$proj_check%' AND `Whiteboard` LIKE '$white_check%' AND `OHP` LIKE '$ohp_check%' AND `WheelchairAccess` LIKE '$wheel_check%' AND `lectureCapture` LIKE '$cap_check%' AND `Style` LIKE '$roomtype%'"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);
if ($result == FALSE) die ("could not execute statement $query<br />");
echo "<form action='' method='post'>";
echo "<table>"; 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){                           
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['roomCode'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Style'] . "</td><td>" . $row['dataProjector'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Whiteboard'] . "</td><td>" . $row['OHP'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['wheelchairAccess'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['lectureCapture'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='radio' name='radioSelect' value= '". $row['roomCode']."'></td>";
}
echo "<input type='submit' name='ttroom' id='ttroom' name='ttroom'>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>"; 
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: there is a stray / spare `form` tag in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem, but I think that your solution is simply, create a header row BEFORE the while condition. It's to say:

```
...
    echo "<table>"; 
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th>Title 1</th>';
    echo '<th>Title 2</th>';
    echo '<th>Title 3</th>';
    echo '<th>Title 4</th>';
    echo '<th>Title 5</th>';
    echo '</tr>';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){                           
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row['roomCode'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Style'] . "</td><td>" . $row['dataProjector'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Whiteboard'] . "</td><td>" . $row['OHP'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['wheelchairAccess'] . "</td>";
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just insert the `<th>`'s after `echo "<table>";` , like so:

```
echo '<tr>
        <th>Title 1</th>
        <th>Title 2</th>
        <!-- add as many as you need -->
      </tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add, before you iterate through the recordset, a new row with the relevant column headers. Typically you might use a `th` tag though it could be a standard `td` tag if you wished.

```
<?php 

    $numeroOption= $_POST['numero'];
    $roomtype= $_POST['roomtype'];
    $selectOption = $_POST['parkname'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `ROOMS` WHERE `Capacity` < '$numeroOption' AND `Park` LIKE '$selectOption%' AND `dataProjector` LIKE '$proj_check%' AND `Whiteboard` LIKE '$white_check%' AND `OHP` LIKE '$ohp_check%' AND `WheelchairAccess` LIKE '$wheel_check%' AND `lectureCapture` LIKE '$cap_check%' AND `Style` LIKE '$roomtype%'"; 
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if ($result == FALSE) die ("could not execute statement $query<br />");

    echo "<form action='' method='post'>";
    echo "<table>
            <tr>
                <th scope='col'>Room Code</th>
                <th scope='col'>Style</th>
                <th scope='col'>Projector</th>
                <th scope='col'>Whiteboard</th>
                <th scope='col'>OHP</th>
                <th scope='col'>Wheelchair Access</th>
                <th scope='col'>Lecture Capture</th>
                <th scope='col'>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){                           
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row['roomCode'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Style'] . "</td><td>" . $row['dataProjector'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Whiteboard'] . "</td><td>" . $row['OHP'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['wheelchairAccess'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['lectureCapture'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td><input type='radio' name='radioSelect' value= '". $row['roomCode']."'></td></tr>";
    }
    echo "<input type='submit' name='ttroom' id='ttroom' name='ttroom'>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>"; 
    echo "</form>";

?>
```

Something I didn't notice immediately is the lack of closing `tr` tag within the loop - there is only one closing `tr` tag and it is outside the loop!
To add the column headers dynamically based upon the actual field names ( which is what I initially thought you were wanting to do, you could use an approach like this:-

```
<?php 

    $numeroOption= $_POST['numero'];
    $roomtype= $_POST['roomtype'];
    $selectOption = $_POST['parkname'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `ROOMS` WHERE `Capacity` < '$numeroOption' AND `Park` LIKE '$selectOption%' AND `dataProjector` LIKE '$proj_check%' AND `Whiteboard` LIKE '$white_check%' AND `OHP` LIKE '$ohp_check%' AND `WheelchairAccess` LIKE '$wheel_check%' AND `lectureCapture` LIKE '$cap_check%' AND `Style` LIKE '$roomtype%'"; 
    $result = mysql_query( $query );
    if ( $result == FALSE ) die ("could not execute statement $query<br />");





    /* an array to store column names */
    $colheaders=array();

    /* find how many fields in each row there are */
    $iCols=mysql_num_fields( $result );

    /* Get the column names */
    for( $i=0; $i < $iCols; $i++ ) $colheaders[]=mysql_field_name( $result, $i );

    /* Add an item for the radio buttons */
    $colheaders[]='Options';

    /* ensure all of recordset is available to iterate through after getting field names*/
    mysql_data_seek( $result, 0 );



    echo "<form action='' method='post'>";
    echo "<table>
            <tr>";

    foreach( $colheaders as $colname ) echo "<th scope='col'>{$colname}</th>";

    echo "
            </tr>";

    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ){                         
        echo "
        <tr>
            <td>" . $row['roomCode'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['Style'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['dataProjector'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['Whiteboard'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['OHP'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['wheelchairAccess'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['lectureCapture'] . "</td>
            <td><input type='radio' name='radioSelect' value= '". $row['roomCode']."'></td>
        </tr>";
    }

    echo "
            <tr>
                <td colspan='".count($colheaders)."'><input type='submit' name='ttroom' id='ttroom' name='ttroom'></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it dynamically.

Inside your `while` loop, use `if` to check for the existence of a non-existing variable. Then, set that variable inside the `if`. This way, you only go into the `if` the first time through the loop. Then, inside the `if`, you can loop over your first `$row` and use its keys as your column header titles:

```
<?php
$numeroOption= $_POST['numero'];
$roomtype= $_POST['roomtype'];
$selectOption = $_POST['parkname'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM `ROOMS` WHERE `Capacity` < '$numeroOption' AND `Park` LIKE '$selectOption%' AND `dataProjector` LIKE '$proj_check%' AND `Whiteboard` LIKE '$white_check%' AND `OHP` LIKE '$ohp_check%' AND `WheelchairAccess` LIKE '$wheel_check%' AND `lectureCapture` LIKE '$cap_check%' AND `Style` LIKE '$roomtype%'"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);
if ($result == FALSE) die ("could not execute statement $query<br />");
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <table>
    <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) : ?>
        <?php if (!isset($headersDone)) : $headersDone = true; ?>
        <tr>
            <?php foreach ($row as $key => $value) : ?>
            <th><?php echo $key; ?></th>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>                     
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['roomCode']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Style']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['dataProjector']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Whiteboard']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['OHP']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['wheelchairAccess']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['lectureCapture']; ?></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="radioSelect" value="<?php echo $row['roomCode']; ?>"></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
        <input type="submit" name="ttroom" id="ttroom" name="ttroom">
    </table> 
</form>
```

You'll also notice I reformatted a bunch of your mixed PHP/HTML code. Just my opinion, but I think it can be made to look a lot cleaner by breaking out of the `<?php ?>` tags instead of a bunch of `echo`s. PHP's [alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) is nice for this scenario